# Getting parent class of a div when the div is rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have:

```
<div class="foo">
 <div class="bar">
 </div></div>
```

When "bar" is rendered, I'd like to check if "bar" is in "foo", and if so, what the class name is.

What is not working:

```
<div class="foo">
 <div class="bar">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(this).load(function(){
      var parentClass= $(this).parent().attr('class');

    });
  </script>
 </div></div>
```

If "bar" is in "foo", I want to hide "bar", if not, display it, so I would:

```
if(parentClass.indexOf('foo') > -1) $(this).hide();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If "bar" is in "foo", I want to hide "bar":

Just target any child .bar of .foo ?

```
$('.foo .bar').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.foo').each(function () {
    if ($(this).find('div.bar').length) $(this).find('div.bar').hide();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/DVREX/)**

---

This can even be done with no JavaScript at all (only CSS):

```
.foo .bar {
    display:none;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/DVREX/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(this).load(function(){
      if($(this).parent().is('.foo'))
      {
        $(this).hide()
      }
   });
</script>
```

BTW, load will work for images i believe

Answer (score 0):

`div`s don't have a load event, and regardless, in that context, `this` is (I think) the window. Try selecting all `.bar` elements in a DOM ready handler and doing whatever you need then.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.foo > .bar').hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mSAMw/

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing document.ready with the load function. Also, here is an easy way of hiding 'bar' only if they are within a foo.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    if ($('.foo').find('.bar').length > 0) {
        $('.bar').hide();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if ($('.bar').parent().hasClass('foo')){     
$('.bar').hide();
}
```

[**Demo**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/U4g93/)